# Superimposing Images in Catplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, catplot

I am attempting to superimpose dot plots on top of a bar graph. Both types of plots have been generated using seaborn's catplot function.

Scatter-plot Code:

```
dotplot2 = sns.catplot(x="Group", y="MASQ_Score", col= "MASQ_Item", units="subject", aspect=.6, hue="Group", ci = 68, data=df_reshaped)
```

Resulting Plot Image:

[image: Scatter-plot]

Bar-plot Code:

```
barplot2 = sns.catplot(x="Group", y="MASQ_Score", hue='Group', kind="bar", col= "MASQ_Item", units="subject", aspect=.6, ci = 68, data=df_reshaped)
```

Resulting Plot Image:

[image: Bar-Plot]

Does anyone know if there is a way to superimpose the scatter-plot data on top of the bar-plot? So that both types of information are conveniently visible.

Comment: I would guess the idea is to create a `FacetGrid` and `map` a `barplot` and a `stripplot` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment, here is a working solution with open data using the `map_dataframe` method from `FacetGrid`:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time")
g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot,x="sex", y="total_bill")
g.map_dataframe(sns.boxplot,x="sex", y="total_bill",boxprops={'facecolor':'None'},showfliers = False)
```

[image: Output result]

The `stirpplot` and `boxplot` can easily be replaced by other seaborn components like `swarmplot` or `violinplot`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are plotting is not a scatter plot, it is a stirpplot. As @Rachid Riad shows. If what you are looking for is to make a barplot instead of a `boxplot`, you just have to change that line to:

```
sns.barplot()
```

I would personally recommend using `boxplot` and `swarmplot`.